# Where in the world wide web is Troggy?

Tags: discussion

Troggy, one of our moderators, appears to have been MIA for several months now. His last activity on both Meta and [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/2553/troggy) are dating back to July 28th at last.

He appears to log in daily, but there's no chat, no activity.

**So where in the world wide web is Troggy?**

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hnvp3.png

Comment: @Sathya yeah, he's around, but he's one quiet dragon

Comment: -1 This question does not show any research effort ;) *For any questions/concerns/problems or reason to contact me, you can email me at: [email address in user profile]*?

Comment: Well, Troggy still is a mod, so he will get the automatic inbox notification for this meta post the next time he does log in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the ground shakes...

The smoke clears and a beefy arm connected to an S like green formation appears out of the shadows.

Life changes have gotten the best of Troggy lately, which required a lot of time.  No need to fear though, I am not dead.  In fact, I might have just gotten started...

Comment: Admin it, you just sit in your lair and play [HOARD](http://www.hoardgame.com/) the whole time...

Comment: @DanielBeck  woah, how did I not know about that?  Awesome.  Now if I only had time to play things like that...  (added to steam wish list)

Comment: Thing happens - glad to see you found my message though :)

Comment: @SimonSheehan 011000100110100101110100 happens. ;)